# Django http://127.0.0.0:8000 not displaying results from new Prod/App View

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django.  I created the following Projects/Apps

1. first_project

   - first_app (Hello World - in view)
2. ProTwo

   - AppTwo (My Second App - in view)

The apps just display text at the moment from the views.  Both are set up exact same way.

In the first_project I ran python manage.py runserver and when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000 I see the hello world.

In the AppTwo I ran python manage.py runserver also but when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000 I still get hello world.

How do I resolve this so I display "My Second App" in the browser instead of "Hello World"?.

I've followed the steps in the course including information here

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_creating_project.htm

It is showing results from first Proj/App -> Hello World and NOT "My Second App"

Comment: Do you try to run both the apps in the same time or you are stopping the first one and after that running the second one?

Comment: Two processes can't listen on the same port (`8000`). Start the second one on a different port, such as `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just run the second server with a different port ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:

Comment: That worked.  I ran:

python manage.py runserver 8001

Question I have is why did I have to do this?

Comment: Figured something out.  When I ran "python manage.py runserver" I would press Ctrl+C.  This was ending the environment.  Thx

Comment: In the first case scenario you are running 2 servers which are pointing to exactly the same place. That is why you are seeing the same result. When you press Ctrl+C you are stopping the process and you can run your next command.